# How to transform the ticker just like ‘EURUSD’ to ‘EUR_USD’?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I got the ticker from syminfo.ticker just like ‘EURUSD’,and sent to oanda through autoview but not accepted because the ticker shall be ‘EUR_USD’.

How do I add ‘_’ in the middle of ticker in pine-script?

Thanks.

Comment: Are the pairs you are trading always follow the `3 letters_3 letters` format?

Comment: No,sometimes 5_3，because it's not all 3_3 in Oanda.When testing with Binance,it might 5_4.(USDT)

Answer (score 0):

I try to use this code to solve the adding "_" problem.Is it correct?

```
var symbol = str.substring(syminfo.ticker,0, str.length(syminfo.ticker)-str.length(syminfo.currency)) + '_' + syminfo.currency
```